# Laravel5.3:How to use pluck in relationship for bindign Form::select element?

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship, pluck

This is my model:

```
class Positions extends Model implements Repository
{
    protected $fillable = ['index_id', 'title', 'description'];

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('TEST\Indices', 'index_id');
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->with('index')->find($id);
    }
}
```

how to use `pluck()` in `getById()` function for listing index relationship?

Comment: What is the field in the `index` relation that you want pluck ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
return $this->with('index')->find($id)->pluck('index.indexField');
```

Comment: return $this->with('index')->find($id)->pluck('index.id', 'index.code');//Erorr:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'index.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `index`.`id` from `positions`)

Comment: Can you print the structure of what you get after calling `getById` ?